# Session variable not passing between files

Tags: php, session

Im trying to pass a session variable $_SESSION['id'] form one page to another. But in the page im trying to pass it to I get this error
Undefined index id

The pages are in different dirs but in the same parent dir obviously, would this have anything to do with it?

This is the first file

```
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['category'])){
  // cast the category to integer (just a little bit of basic security)
  $cat = (int) $_POST['category'];
  $q = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat=$cat AND status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
  $result = $link->query($q);
  // this will be the string that you will return into the product-data div
  $returnHtml = '';
 }
 else if(isset($_POST['subcategory'])){
  // cast the category to integer (just a little bit of basic security)
  $subcat = (int) $_POST['subcategory'];
  $q = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE subcat=$subcat AND status =1 ORDER BY id DESC";
  $result = $link->query($q);
  // this will be the string that you will return into the product-data div
  $returnHtml = '';
 }
     // construct the html to return
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $returnHtml .= "<div class='product'>"; 
    $returnHtml .= "<a href='products.php' target='_blank''>";
    $returnHtml .= "<img class='nailthumb-container'";
    $returnHtml .= "src='{$row['image']}' ";;
    $returnHtml .= "alt='{$row['name']}' ";
    $returnHtml .= "title='{$row['name']}' />";
    $returnHtml .= "</a>";
    $returnHtml .= "<span class='productname1'>{$row['name']}</span>";
    $returnHtml .= "<br />";
    $returnHtml .= "<br />";
    $returnHtml .= "<span class='productprice1'>&pound {$row['price']}</span>";
    $returnHtml .= "</div>";
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
}

// display the html (you actually return it this way)
echo $returnHtml;
```

This is the second

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div class="productconainer">
           <?php
              $id = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
              $result = $link->query($id);
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['image'];
     }
           ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are sessions configured on the server?

Comment: use `phpinfo()` and check the sessions are configured ok on the server

Comment: I'm using wamp and sessions work for other sites ive done!

Answer (score 0):

I think Undefined index: id is on this line:

```
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
```

if `!isSet($_POST['category'])` and `!isSet($_POST['subcategory'])`
variable **$row** is not defined.

Comment: what he is trying to say is that the location your setting the session variable on first file is such that the $row variable is out of scope.

Comment: No, what he's trying to say is that when you get to the line pointed out in the answer, `$row` has already been set to `null`.  PHP is function-scoped, so `$row` is certainly not out of scope.

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong $_SESSION['id']=$row['id']; is actually in the while loop.

Comment: If i echo $_SESSIO['id'] in the first file it holds the correct value, but if i echo it in the second file, nothing! i have edited my first file to show it in the while loop

Comment: Undefined index is from my query in the second file!

Comment: Try session_name(); after session_start();

Comment: try echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);exit; after session_start(); in the second file...

Comment: Thats givg me this Array
(
    [id] => 1
)

Comment: The id of the link i clicked is 20.

Comment: i just tried echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION['id']);exit; and its echoing 1...........

Comment: unfortunatley not, its echoing 1 but the id should be 20!

Comment: You're all going to think im super obtuse, but i had session_start in a file which included my first file. When i removed it from there and put it actually in my first file it worked as it should. Feel quite silly now!